# Let u ∈ R× be a unit. Show that d|x if and only if d|(u · x). Show that d|x if and only if (u · d)|x.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let u ∈ R× be a unit. Show that $d|x$ if and only if $d|(u · x)$. Show that $d|x$ if and
only if $(u · d)|x$.

As I understand it, since u is a unit, there exists some element v ∈ R× such that: $u·v = v·u = 1R$, where 1R is the multiplicative identity.

For example, in Z the units are $1$ and $-1$, because $1·1=1$ and $(-1)·(-1)=1$.

In which case it is clear that $d|x$ if and only if $d|(1·x)$ and $d|(-1·x)$.

It is also clear that $d|x$ if and only if $(1 · d)|x$ and $(-1·d)|x$.

I don't see how to show this is true in general.

I think it has something to do with the fact that we can say $u|1R$ because $u*v=1R$.

Comment: $a\mid b$ is $ac=b$. If $u$ is a unit, $au(u^{-1}c)=b$, so $au\mid b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $d \mid x$. Then $x = md$ for some $m \in R$. Now multiply both sides by $u$ to obtain $ux = umd$, so $d|ux$. Now suppose $d \mid ux$, i.e. $ux = md$ for some $m\in R$. Let $v \in R$ such that $vu = 1$. Then multiplying both sides by $v$, we find $vux = vmd \implies x = vmd$. So $d\mid x$.

The proof for your second fact is quite similar, so I leave this to you. Feel free to comment if you need more help!